# Question/Confusion About iptables on Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 and How to Use iptables Without UFW

Tags: iptables, firewall, 17.04, ufw

so as my title mentions, I want to use iptables without having UFW to manage it in Ubuntu Desktop 17.04. Having used iptables in CentOS 7 and Ubuntu Server 17.04, I am not achieving the same results I did in those two. Examples of commands I run that I am expecting to work as they did in the other two are:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo systemctl start iptables
```

My results have been that my first command does not seem to register, and my second command returns the following error : `Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.`

I have tried completely uninstalling UFW by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ufw
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo aptitude remove ufw
```

I have installed `iptables-persistent` and saved my rules by running `sudo /sbin/iptables-save`. Of course, I also ran updates and rebooted my system after all was done.

I've even tried reinstalling iptables, but still no luck. I run into the same issues as mentioned earlier. What am I missing/not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same, and I have the same issue (I am also coming from Centos).

I ran nmap and it appears that iptables are properly running (even after a reboot). I suggest you run it too.

nmap -P0 192.168.0.8

nmap -P0 -sU 192.168.0.8